# csv data with d3 doesn't work

Tags: django, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to load data from a csv-File to create a pie chart.

I found a example and copied it to test it. But it doesn't work. It seems that I'm the only one with this Problem. Whats my fault? Can someone help me?

My html-file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}
</style>

<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.population; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.population = +d.population;
  });

  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.age); });

  g.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.age; });
});
</script>
```

and the csv:

```
 age,population
<5,2704659
5-13,4499890
14-17,2159981
18-24,3853788
25-44,14106543
45-64,8819342
≥65,612463
```

Perhaps I have to edit, that I'm using it with django. Without django it works.
So here is my view:

```
def test(request):

t = get_template('test.html')
html = t.render()
return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: My guess would be the `url` of `data.csv` is different when served by django.

Comment: What do you mean with different? If i open the html with a Browser it works, but if I run the django-server it doesn't work. But that are the same files!

Comment: You have to read up on how django serves static files. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

Comment: Ok your right :D I totally forgot this :/ Its working now! Thank you!

Comment: I am around the same kind of issue ...I have a view that's allow me to download file, but I can't catch it through the d3.read_csv -> the download automatically goes to 'Download' folder... def some_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="cars.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    import pandas as pd
    x = pd.read_csv('./static/cars.csv')
    writer.writerow(x.columns)
    writer.writerow(["%.2f"%c for c in x[0:1].values[0]])
    return response